# Problem with formula inside a conditional formatting rule

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

why i can't combine formula with conditional formatting, if i compare two values or two cells values inside a conditional formatting rule it works, but if i compare a cell value with a formula it doesn't work

[image]

I have two column table with Date and quantity, I created in another cell an xlookup formula to get the corresponding quantity of the date entered and it works fine, then in the next cell I compared this xlookup formula with the value of the previous cell and it gives me "TRUE" result, so what i did is to copy the whole formula of the cell which gives me TRUE result without the equal sign of corse and paste it in a conditional formatting new rule but i get nothing, nothing happen, why i can't combine formula with conditional formatting

[image]

Comment: Remove the inverted quotes or speech marks `""` from the formulas in conditional formatting, only use the formula `=$E$5=XLOOKUP(E3,Table1[[date ]],Table1[qty])`